# MX Record Answer Contains Same Domain

Tags: domain-name-system, mx-record

What does it mean for an `MX` record to have an answer section that contains itself? My earlier belief was that this implies that a domain is it's own mail domain, but from running a couple experiments on web domains, I get connection timeouts when doing `SMTP` scans on domains that have `MX` records as below.

Which RFC / where in an RFC contains this specification?

```
$ dig -t mx yahoo.net                                                                                                                                                

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.7-Ubuntu <<>> -t mx yahoo.net                                                                                                                                           
;; global options: +cmd                                                                                                                                                                            
;; Got answer:                                                                                                                                                                                     
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 29654                                                                                                                                          
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1                                                                                                                               

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:                                                                                                                                                                              
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;yahoo.net.                     IN      MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.net.              1800    IN      MX      0 .

;; Query time: 175 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53)
;; WHEN: [REDACTED] UTC 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 53
```

Other domains that have `MX` records like this: 
`umblr.com`, `google.az`, `ardmediathek.de`, `huffingtonpost.ca`, `yimg.com`, `healthdirect.gov.au`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, as a general observation, the name `.` does not refer to "the domain itself" but to the root of the DNS tree.

Specifically in the context of `MX`, though, [the rdata `0 .` has been defined to mean "null"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7505#section-3), as in "I do not want mail delivered".

No `MX`, on the other hand, has a completely different meaning; [try delivering to the address directly associated with this name instead](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-5) (in practice this is often some web server).

Comment: Do you have a source for the last paragraph?

Comment: @Wilson added a link for that

Comment: Thanks this a much clearer answer I’ve accept this one

Answer (score 1):

Actually yahoo.net mx record points to . which means that it does not have proper MX record at all. In such situations hosts sometimes accept entries in A records, but it is not the case here.

as for RFC you can start from rfc974 and newer.

Comment: I’m scanning 25.

Comment: i cannot reach that port in yahoo.net either.

Comment: What’s strange is that I cannot reach 25 for all the example domains in my question.

Comment: try other smtp ports, like tls. might be a network problem or hosts are not listening on 25 port. some network providers filter 25 port for antispam reasons, but if you can reach 25 port of other hosts - that might not be a issue.

Comment: *sorry, my bad phrasing, it appears that I am unable to reach 25 on any of the hosts that have a MX record like this. I will try out other ports to see :)

Comment: i was wrong in previous answers - check my updated answer ;)

Comment: Hi, I have a short follow up before I accept. How did you figure out it points to . and what is . in the context of MX records?

Comment: ;; ANSWER SECTION:
yahoo.net.              1800    IN      MX      0 .

and mx should point to FQDN (basically full domain name) according to RFC

Comment: Ah so “.” is not a FQDN? I remember seeing it refers to the domain itself?

Comment: FQDN should be full hostname.domain.com (might be domain.com as well if that is intented). . does not resolve here in IP address. You might be right regarding . refering to the domain itself, but I cannot recall it and in the RFC I could not quickly find that as acceptable MX record. 

MX and some other records require . in the end, so probably yahoo.net could not enter MX record without a . at all. 

Also you could try mxtoolbox to verify mx records.

Comment: "." is the root of DNS. Try `dig -t ns .` for example.